# List not updating on deleting item

Tags: listview, flutter

I am deleting an item from the list view. It is successfully deleting but it is not updating on UI. It updates when I go back to previous screen and come again again to the screen where I deleted the item. I am using Dismissible for deleting item.

Below is the code where I am setting the list view

```
 Expanded(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: data.length,
          itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => DataItem(
            data: data[i],
            shopList: widget.shopList,
            ),
        ),
      )
```

And this my code in DataItem:

```
return Dismissible(
  key: UniqueKey(),
  background: Container(
    color: Theme.of(context).errorColor,
    child: Icon(
      Icons.delete,
      color: Colors.white,
      size: 40,
    ),
    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
      horizontal: 15,
      vertical: 4,
    ),
  ),
  direction: DismissDirection.endToStart,
  confirmDismiss: (direction) {
    return showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (ctx) => AlertDialog(
        title: Text('Are you sure?'),
        content: Text('Do you want to remove from the cart?'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            child: Text('No'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(ctx).pop(false);
            },
          ),
          FlatButton(
            child: Text('Yes'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(ctx).pop(true);
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  },
  onDismissed: (direction) {

    setState(() {
      deleteCartItem(widget.data.id);
      String gen =  widget.data.toString();

    });
  },
  child: Card(
    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
      horizontal: 15,
      vertical: 4,
    ),
    child: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
      child: ListTile(
        leading: CircleAvatar(
          backgroundColor: AppColors.purple,
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
            child: FittedBox(
              child: Text(
                widget.generation.price,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        title: Text(widget.generation.title),
        subtitle: Text(
          'Total: \$${(widget.data.price * 1)}',
        ),

      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: can you post full class code ?the code you have posted looks okay.

Comment: What is `deleteCartItem(widget.data.id);` ?

Comment: @AdityaNigam It is a method for deleting item

Comment: @USER9561 it looks like the function isn't working properly. Possibly a delayed operation? upload the code for that as well

Comment: @AdityaNigam the function is working properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this using Provider. I was using sqflite previously for getting the data globally. Now after changing everything to Provider I resolved this issue